# Error:Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<User>'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2

In my Angular-Firebase online shopping project I used `AuthGuard` to check whether user is logged in or not to access `./check-out` and other links as shown in code below. Getting an error as the `map` doesn't get imported for `Observable.User` in code below. Using everything of latest version.
**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  user$: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { 
    this.user$=afAuth.authState;
  }

  login(){
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
  }
  logout(){
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut()
  }
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import { AuthService } from './../auth.service'
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent{

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  login(){
    this.auth.login();
  }

}
```

**bs-navbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'bs-navbar',
  templateUrl: './bs-navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bs-navbar.component.css']
})
export class BsNavbarComponent{

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {
   }

  logout(){
    this.auth.logout();
  }
}
```

**bs-navbar.component.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">O</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/shopping-cart">Shopping cart</a>
        </li>
        <ng-template #anonymousUser>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
          </li>
        </ng-template>
        <li ngbDropdown *ngIf="auth.user$ | async as user; else anonymousUser" class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a ngbDropdownToggle class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            {{user.displayName}}
          </a>
          <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/my/orders">My Orders</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/admin/orders">Manage Orders</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/admin/products">Manage Prodcuts</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="logout()">Log Out</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

**auth.guard.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate{
   constructor(private auth:AuthService, private router: Router) {
   }
   canActivate(): boolean{
   return this.auth.user$.map(user=>{
      if(user) return true;
      this.router.navigate(['./login']);
      return false;
      });
   }
}
```

Getting error in **auth.guard.service.ts** in `return this.auth.user$.map(user=>` line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using the newest version of RxJS, it is probably because the `map` operator must be piped like this:

```
return this.auth.user$.pipe(map(user => ...));
```

You can see an example of this in here :https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html